# Salvar um valor da TextView e adicionar outro

Tags: java, android

Estou Criando um teclado pra adicionar valor a uma TextView. Consegui adicionar um valor apenas a TextView. Mas o que queria fazer era manter o valor atual e adicionar outro ao lado pra que o usuário faça um numero para adicionar a TextView.

No evento Onclick Fiz isso:

```
 switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonNum1:
                txtNum.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonNum2:
                txtNum.setText("2");
                break;
```

Gostaria de saber como faço pra manter o valor atual e adicionar um novo valor ao lado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que seu objeto `txtNum` seja um `TextView`, você pode usar o método `append`.

```
txtNum.append("1");
```

Se `txtNum` for um objeto que não possua uma função `append`, você sempre pode fazer algo como `x = x + y, ex:`

```
txtNum.setText(txtNum.getText() + "1");
```

Comment: muito obrigado, não conhecia o append

Comment: como eu posso fazer para apagar o ultimo digitado?

Comment: Desconheço uma função para isso, teria que ser manual. Se for sempre inserido apenas um caractere por vez é mais facil, pode remover com obj.setText(obj.getText().subString(0, obj.getText().length() - 2));. Já se for possível inserir qualquer tipo de texto, ai você poderia ter uma veriavel para a ultima inserção e usar essa variavel em conjunto com lastIndexOf() para fazer o substring.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente so tive que alterar umas coisasobj.setText(obj.getText().subSequence(0, obj.getText().length() - 1));